Using formset in django formtool
I am creating an 8 step form wizard. 2 of the models are Qualification and SSCE and I used formset to create multiple forms inputs
Formset factory
QualificationsFormSet = modelformset_factory(Qualifications, form=QualificationsForm, extra=5)
SscesFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ssces, form=SSCESubjectForm, extra=5)

The View
class StudentWizard(LoginRequiredMixin, SessionWizardView):
    form_list = FORMS
    # template_name = 'admission/form_wizard.html'
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location='/tmp/')
    
        
    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current
        form = super().get_form(step, data, files)
        form.request = self.request
        
        if step == '3':
            form = QualificationsFormSet(data, queryset=Qualifications.objects.none())
        elif step == '4':
            form = SscesFormSet(data, queryset=Ssces.objects.none())
        
        return form
    
    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        print(f"Current step: {step}")
        if step == '4':  # SSCE step
            qualifications = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('3')
            print(f"Qualifications data: {qualifications}")
            if qualifications:
                certificates = [qual['certificate_obtained'] for qual in qualifications]
                print(f"Certificates: {certificates}")
                if not any(cert in ['WASC', 'SSCE', 'NECO', 'GCE'] for cert in certificates):
                    print("Skipping SSCE step")
                    return None  # Skip the Ssces formset

        return super().get_form_instance(step)
    
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)  
        if self.steps.current in ["3", "4"]:
            context['formset'] = form
            context['formset_with_widgets'] = [
                [(field, field.field.widget.__class__.__name__) for field in form]
                for form in context['formset'].forms
            ]
        else:
            context['fields_with_widgets'] = [
                (field, field.field.widget.__class__.__name__) for field in form
            ]
            
        return context

The problem is that the other forms works well up to the Qualification, where after submitting the formset for the qualification, the wizard still returns to the qualification template instead of progressing to the ssce.html template.

Secondly, it returns an empty form of the qualification template after the first submission

I have used debug to check where the error would have been. I noticed it's around get_form() and get_form_instance().
The core seems to be alright. I don't know where I messed it up.
